# C++ reading CSVs

Tags: c++, parsing, csv, format

Im having a bit of trouble reading CSVs. I have multiple types of data, so i am not sure how to get this to work:

`string, string, bool, bool, int`

I cant simply use `>>` to read in the data since the deliminator is not whitespace. `scanf` doesnt work, since it needs a human input, not file input, `getline` only reads in strings and also includes the `\n` char for some reason.

how can i read my csv properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c

Comment: the  coded strings are what i have tried. the bit of trouble is that i dont know how to get the values into their respective variables in my program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You CAN use getline. There's an overload where the third argument passed can be a char for the delimiter. Just throw it all in a loop

Comment: i did use `getline(filestream, str, ',')`. however, its also reading to the next line(since there is no closing comma), so all the values are erroring like crazy

Comment: When you read the int, use '\n' as the delimiter. Read all 5 per iteration

Comment: cool thanks! i cant believe i didnt think of that. one final question: what should be the terminating condition for the while loop? `file.eof()` is running into errors

Answer (score 2):

Another option (which isn't typically recommended for C++, though), is [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/). You're right that `scanf` is no good for you, but `fscanf` is its file-based equivalent.

Another canonical solution typically employed in C, but which isn't so strongly recommended in C++, is to go ahead and use `getline`, and then use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) or a simple parser to parse each line.